# Why is Visual Studio failing to copy a dll to my web directory (IIS file locking issue)?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, publish, file-locking

What is causing these frustrating errors during every Visual Studio build operation?

> Could not copy "obj\Debug\mywebapp.dll" to "bin\mywebapp.dll".
>   Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. Unable to copy file
>   "obj\Debug\mywebapp.dll" to "bin\mywebapp.dll". The process cannot
>   access the file 'bin\mywebapp.dll' because it is being used by another
>   process.

I'm fairly certain that w3wp.exe is locking the file, because the error stops if I restart or shut down IIS from IIS manager.  ProcessExplorer shows that w3wp and visual studio are the only processes with locks on the file.  Obviously IIS is the issue, because the compilation succeeds when IIS is restarted.

I am using dynamic assemblies loaded into a child application domain.  Could those be referencing the file?  I tried added an event handler to the Global.asax application_end event to ensure the child app domain is unloaded, but the handler never runs.  Also, the debugger's "modules" window shows various modules, but the AppDomain field is always blank, so I cannot even determine if that might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've set up your web application within Visual Studio to use Local IIS for debugging:

[image]

Comment: That setting is irrelevant, as I'm choosing "Build" not "Debug", and it's already set to use Local IIS already.  I cannot even use the Visual Studio Dev server anyway, because it does not support the WSS (web-socket-secure) protocol that my web application uses, and as a grant-funded project at a university we have only one server available on this project running Server 2012 + IIS 8 (bare minimum for web socket support).

Comment: The web site's virtual directory is pointed to my main project directory so changes are observable immediately upon compilation without any extra deployment steps (there were problems with web deploy, including it taking too long), but the real questions are why IIS is locking the main project DLL file, and is stopping the web app pool temporarily a necessary or intrinsic operation to deployment?  I'm assuming it has to lock the file to use it, and there must be utility or process for releasing the file for update.  I just wish it was built into visual studio.

Comment: Typically for debugging, I just manually attach the debugger to the w3wp.exe process so I can debug live requests to ensure everything is working properly, so that's why I say the project settings you mentioned are not effective in my situation.

Comment: If you set your project to use 'Local IIS Web Server' as per the screenshot, when you hit F5 to run the application, Visual Studio will automatically attach itself to IIS for debugging. I do this all the time and never encounter locked DLLs, and yes you are right - the DLLs are locked because the w3wp.exe process is using them to run the application. AFAIK, when you set 'Local IIS Web Server' and hit F5, VS is capable of doing an app recycle before build to unlock the DLLs. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the exact same error. I deleted my old Web Application/Web Site from IIS and created a brand new one with a different name (not sure if you have to have a different name but that worked for me). Now it all works great!